# How to return rows matched in a table without multiple EXISTS clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to pull back results from one table that match **ALL** specified values where the specified values are in another table. I can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts 
WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ContactClassifications WHERE ContactID = Contacts.ID AND ClassificationID =  '8C62E5DE-00FC-4994-8127-000B02E10DA5')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ContactClassifications WHERE ContactID = Contacts.ID AND ClassificationID =  'D2E90AA0-AC93-4406-AF93-0020009A34BA')
AND EXISTS etc...
```

However that falls over when I get up to about 40 EXISTS clauses. The error message is "The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query."

Comment: How about just using an IN clause on ClassificationID?

Comment: The problem with an IN clause is that it matches ANY ClassificationID. I want it to match ALL ClassificationIDs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gist of this is to

- Select all contacts with any GUID from the `IN` statement
- Use a `DISTINCT COUNT` to get a count for each contactid on matching GUID's
- Use the `HAVING` to retain only those contacts that equal the amount of matching GUID's you've put into the `IN` statement

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Contacts c
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT c.ID
          FROM   dbo.Contacts c
                 INNER JOIN dbo.ContactClassifications cc ON c.ID = cc.ContactID
          WHERE  cc.ClassificationID IN ('..', '..', 38 other GUIDS)
          GROUP BY
                 c.ID
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cc.ClassificationID) = 40
       ) cc ON cc.ID = c.ID
```

Test script at [data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71773/how-to-return-rows-matched-in-a-table-without-multiple-exists-clauses)

Comment: The OP asks "ALL values in another table", not all values passed to the query and then placed in an IN clause

Comment: If your input is a list of GUID's, then this is a right answer :)

Comment: @Andomar - thx, I've missed that. To OP, can we assume that the other table is **not** ContactClassifications? In the end, it would make this statement less error prone compared to this IN statement. The IN statement could be replaced with an INNER JOIN and the count can be looked up in the other table.

Comment: @Lieven - not sure I get you. The input is a list of GUID's that the user has selected from a checkboxlist. The checkbox list is populated from the Classifications table. So the ContactClassifications is the relationship between Contact and Classification. We want the result to be all the contacts that are linked to all the specified classifications. Does that help?

Comment: @Colin - If your input is a list of GUID's where the contact should have each GUID, the statement as is would be sufficient. If this answer doesn't answer your question, you should remove the accepted flag and leave it open for others to chime in.

Comment: The input is a list of GUID's, and I want to return contacts that have each GUID so I believe you have answered my question already. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to demand that no classification exists without a matching contact.  That's a double negation:

```
select  *
from    contacts c
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    ContactClassifications cc
        where   not exists
                (
                select  *
                from    ContactClassifications cc2
                where   cc2.ContactID = c.ID
                        and cc2.ClassificationID = cc.ClassificationID
                )
        )
```

This type of problem is known as [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Comment: ...not sure if this is right, but finally somebody read the question & his comments!

Comment: you need his list of Classification ID's in there somewhere

Comment: @Gerrat: the query demands that the contact has all classifications in the ContactClassifications table.  As the question asks, "ALL values in another table"

Comment: OP clarified - he wants all "Specified" values (but I like this technique)!

Comment: +1 on the *relational division* link. If you hear a bang, don't worry... It's my head exploding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Contacts c
INNER JOIN 
 (cc.ContactID, COUNT(DISTINCT cc.ClassificationID) as num_class
  FROM ContactClassifications 
  WHERE  ClassificationID IN (....)
  GROUP BY cc.ContactID 
 ) b ON c.ID = b.ContactID
WHERE b.num_class = [number of distinct values - how many different values you put in "IN"]
```

If you run SQLServer 2005 and higher, you can do pretty much the same with `CROSS APPLY`, supposedly more efficiently